# crear nueva tabla a partir de otra en la base de datos en vb

Tags: vb.net, oracle, vb

tengo creadas tablas en mi base de datos,las cuales se muestran en un datagridview de manera individual, pero al modificar una de ellas, **deseo guardar como nueva tabla dentro de la base de datos**, gracias por adelntado

Comment: Hola Carlos, para que obtengas una respuesta satisfactoria te invito a checar [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: podrías especificar los nombres, algo de la estructura y el códigoq ue tienes en VB actualmente para leerla?